# Why NSDateFormatter returns NULL on 24h locals with a 12h time setup?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Hi Experts of the world,

I ran into a very weird problem:

I am formatting a string representing time from 00-23 (as returned by a Google service) in the following manner:

(passing in a string of lets say 14, should output either 14:00 or 2:00 PM, depends on user local)

```
+(NSString *) formatTime: (NSString *)timeToBeFormatted {

   NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateFormat  setDateFormat:@"HH"];
   NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
   date = [dateFormat dateFromString:timeToBeFormatted];  

   // Convert date object to desired output format
   [dateFormat setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

   timeToBeFormatted = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
   return timeToBeFormatted;
}
```

Everything works fine in all locals worldwide.

However, ONLY if a user has his TIME format set on 12h in a local where the default is 24h the formatter will return NULL ONLY for vales between 12-23.. Pretty weird i would say!

Example:
before formatter 12
 after 12:00 AM
before formatter 13
 after (null)

Any ideas why this could happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved! (inspired by the answers above)..

To solve the issue i am creating a specific Locale, then phrasing the stringToDate using this locale. Then i am creating another Locale with the default users preferences and phrasing the dateBackToString using that locale..

```
+(NSString *) formatTime: (NSString *)timeToBeFormatted
{
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

//ADDED//
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormat setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];

[dateFormat  setDateFormat:@"HH"];
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
date = [dateFormat dateFromString:timeToBeFormatted];  

//ADDED//
NSLocale *defualtLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] init];
[dateFormat setLocale:defualtLocale];

[dateFormat setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
timeToBeFormatted = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];  

return timeToBeFormatted;
}
```

I guess its quite costly for older devices but in the era of ARC and strong phones it works ;)

Comment: Even though this has been assumed as the correct answer for the problem but this would only work for Gregorian Calendar. If user uses other calendars such as Buddhist, then this workaround will not work!

Answer (score 1):

`NSDateFormatter` uses the current locale and time settings for parsing (and outputting) time. If you want to use a specific time format, set the locale for the date formatter yourself.

```
dateFormat.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
```

Also, creating date formatter is *expensive*, if you call this function often you should cache the date formatter in a static variable.

Comment: Thank you Nilsson, However it is important for me to use the current user local for the output since my clients are spread worldwide.. Hence i can not afford to create a specific local for everyone..

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this issue before some time.

Use following code to formate your date as per your need.

```
+(NSDate *)getGMTDateToView:(NSDate *) availableDate formatter:(NSDateFormatter *)timeFormat {


     NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
     [timeFormat setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];


     NSTimeInterval timeZoneOffset = [[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]; 
     NSTimeInterval gmtTimeInterval = [availableDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] + timeZoneOffset;

     [timeFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

     [timeFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
     [timeFormat setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

      enUSPOSIXLocale = nil;
      return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:gmtTimeInterval];

}
```

I found above code from one of apple's document (I have modified(little bit) it as per my need) but unable to find this link right now.